# Computer's screen doesn't switch on after waking up

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

After hitting the `sleep` or `hibernate` buttons (equivalent of `xfce4-session-logout -s`), my screen doesn't switch on when I'm trying to wake my computer up. The computer seems to run correctly since I can heard the sound of the video I was playing before I put the computer into standby mode.

- I thought it was a screen luminosity problem but I see the screen when I switch between tty.
- I have to logout through keyboard shortcut (ctrl+alt+del in arch-linux) or hard-reboot on order to be able to use my computer
- I have found a hack which seems to solve this problem, in order to sleep my computer I can use `sudo echo mem > /sys/power/state` as it's explained in kernel's [power-state documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt).
  But since it's not the equivalent of the previous sleep method, I'm wondering what is the problem.

You will find the logs associated to the both previous commands exported through `journalctl --since xx` command, [as a gist here](https://gist.github.com/adoussot/38d1f5fbdc3e9bd27d08ad5312ae8db7).

**Note**: I used a different user for those two sleep methods (root for `echo mem > ...` and the current user (aldo) for the classic one. But executing `xfce4-session-logout -s` as sudoer didn't change anything)

computer specs:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release

Arch Linux release
LSB_VERSION=1.4
DISTRIB_ID=Arch
DISTRIB_RELEASE=rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Arch Linux"
NAME="Antergos Linux"
VERSION="16.11-Minimal-ISO-Rolling"

$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
xfce

$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:15bd]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 91
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=8]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: That's probably a driver bug. What exact hardware do you have, in particular the graphics card?

Comment: I added my graphics card hardware specs gathered from `lspci -vnn | grep VGA...` Is that enough or should I post others informations ?